# How to set a name for the Jasper report download?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, servlets, jasper-reports

I have declared a bean in jasper-view.xml as follows

```
<bean id="resultsPdf"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.jasperreports.JasperReportsPdfView"
      p:url="classpath:reports/resultsPdfFormat.jrxml"
      p:reportDataKey="datasource">
    <property name="headers">
        <props>
            <prop key="Content-Disposition">
                attachment; filename=results.pdf
            </prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

The method in the controller is as follows

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/results-pdf", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public ModelAndView generateResultsPdf(@RequestParam("year") String year) {

    List<Student> studentList = studentService.getResultsByYear(year);
    JRDataSource jrDataSource = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(studentList);
    Map<String, Object> parameterMap = new HashMap<>();
    parameterMap.put("title", "Results table"));
    parameterMap.put("datasource", jrDataSource);

    return new ModelAndView("resultsPdf", parameterMap);
}
```

At the moment it is working fine. The name of the downloaded file is

> results.pdf

Now I would like to append the year parameter to the file name so that it would read as

> results_YEAR.pdf

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out a way to resolve this matter. Instead of declaring a bean we can achieve the task by changing ***generateResultsPdf*** method

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/results-pdf", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public void generateResultsPdf(@RequestParam("year") String year, HttpServletResponse response) {

    List<Student> studentList = studentService.getResultsByYear(year);
    JRDataSource jrDataSource = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(studentList);
    Map<String, Object> parameterMap = new HashMap<>();
    parameterMap.put("title", "Results table"));
    parameterMap.put("datasource", jrDataSource);

    try {
            JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(RESULTS_PDF_REPORT_PATH);
            JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, parameterMap, jrDataSource);

            String filename = "new-filename.pdf";

            response.setContentType("application/pdf");
            response.addHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" +filename);
            OutputStream outputStream = response.getOutputStream();

            JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfStream(jasperPrint, outputStream);
        } catch (JRException | IOException e) {
            logger.error("Error in generating pdf : {}", e);
        }
}
```